# Reverse architecting software for program comprehension

Tags: software-development, data-visualization, source-code, artificial-intelligence, reverse-engineering

I am trying to perform the competition analysis for our startup in software reverse architecting. For this task, ideally, I need to find existing software that given the source code on input, provides architectural insights to the user or (better) facilitates the global understanding of the program being analyzed.

I have already identified the following indirect competitors:

- Source{d}
- SciTools Understand
- PVS-Studio
- Sourcetrail

However, I call them "indirect" competitors because they just display the source code or relations in it as is, without high-level conclusions in the form of architectural diagrams and metrics.

So can you suggest existing software that makes high-level conclusions about the source code so to represent it as a hierarchy of subsystems?

If you need more details on what I'm talking about, here they are:

- [Most technical: research doc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fzqr4UWcB7nOsttVcs-ahUSyTdl5ko0L)
- [Demo video](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/11919805/demo-of-software-comprehension-tools/)
- [Least technical: the website](https://www.softwarecomprehension.com/)

Comment: What programming language(s) is the system implemented in, i.e. what is the source code that any recommended software will need to parse?

Comment: Software that parses just some language is ok to recommend. It's helpful to know if some similar software ever exists, no matter what languages it processes.